# Odd behavior during timezone conversion

Tags: java, datetime, timezone

I am trying to convert between a date printed out in an EST timezone into a date printed out in GMT/UTC

```
package com.stefano;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;


public class MainEntry {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ParseException 
 */


public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


    String dateTime = "1307011200"; //12:00PM 01 July 2013
    System.out.println("Input -> " + dateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmm");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
    Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
    System.out.println("Intermediate -> " + date);
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println("Output -> " + format.format(date));


    }

}
```

The output it gives is:

```
Input -> 1307011200
Intermediate -> Mon Jul 01 17:00:00 BST 2013
Output -> 1307011600
```

Even though the time difference between EST and GMT is always 5, it is somehow getting involved with BST.

I cannot use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: This gives me a different output of 

Input -> 1307011200
Intermediate -> Mon Jul 01 18:00:00 BST 2013
Output -> 1307011700

Comment: That's extremely odd. I can reproduce it every time as the above output on my machine.

Comment: Also, even more odd - If i change the date String to 1301011200 (1st of Jan), the conversion is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of the SimpleDateFormat.parse(String) method refers to the parse(String, ParsePosition) method, that says:

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. As a result, the calendar's date-time fields and the TimeZone value may have been overwritten, depending on subclass implementations. Any TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations.

According to this you can't use this method to tell the SimpleDateFormat which timezone
the given date is in.
You can fix this method like this:

```
String dateTime = "1307011200"; // 12:00PM 01 July 2013
dateTime += " EST"; // append the timezone information to the input string
System.out.println("Input -> " + dateTime);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmm z"); // tell the formatter to look for the timezone info
Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
System.out.println("Intermediate -> " + date);
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("Output -> " + format.format(date));
```

This will also print the Date object using your local timezone, but it shows a way to parse the dateTime string using a given timezone.

Comment: This *does* work. I cannot believe the normal behaviour of the `SimpleDateFormat` is so far removed from what would be expected from an the API.

Comment: No wonder they are writing the new java.time API in Java 8 :)

Comment: And… No wonder why Java programmers eventually go to [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (until migrating to Java 8's [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) as mentioned by zovits, inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)). Joda-Time is well-worth the bother of adding a dependency to your project.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by zovits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22330213/642706) is correct.

## US East Coast Offset

If by `EST` you mean the east coast of the United States (and parts of Canada), then your statement `the time difference between EST and GMT is always 5` is incorrect. With Daylight Saving Time (DST), the offset may be -05:00 *or* -04:00. Indeed, your specified date-time does have DST in effect.

## Avoid 3-4 Letter Time Zone Codes

Those three or four letter time zone codes are neither standardized nor unique. Avoid them. Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), most of which are continent+city.

## Comparison To Joda-Time

For comparison, here is some [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) example code. The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes bundled with Java are so notoriously troublesome that every Java programmer should move to either Joda-Time or the new [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) [java.time package](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) (inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310)).

While a java.util.Date seems to have a time zone but actually does not, note that a Joda-Time [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) does truly know its own assigned time zone.

Joda-Time uses the ISO 8601 standard for its defaults. You can use other formats as well, as seen with the Montréal example below.

### Example Code

```
String input = "1307011200"; //12:00PM 01 July 2013
DateTimeFormatter formatterSmooshed = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "yyMMddHHmm" );
DateTimeZone timeZoneNewYork = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime dateTimeNewYork = formatterSmooshed.withZone( timeZoneNewYork ).parseDateTime( input );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeNewYork.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
String outputMontréal = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "FF" ).withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ).print( dateTimeNewYork );
String outputSmooshed = formatterSmooshed.print( dateTimeNewYork ); // Expect same as input.
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println( "input: " + input );
System.out.println( "dateTimeNewYork: " + dateTimeNewYork );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "outputMontréal: " + outputMontréal );
System.out.println( "outputSmooshed: " + outputSmooshed );
```

When run…

```
input: 1307011200
dateTimeNewYork: 2013-07-01T12:00:00.000-04:00
dateTimeUtc: 2013-07-01T16:00:00.000Z
outputMontréal: lundi 1 juillet 2013 12 h 00 EDT
outputSmooshed: 1307011200
```